# mouseover() - using addClass() with this

Tags: jquery

how can I add a class when mouse is over an element?

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
    .append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td>')
    .mouseover(function(){
        this.addClass('list_row_mover');
    });
```

js error:

```
this.addClass is not a function
```

Comment: Try using `$(this)` instead of `this`.(just a thought)

Comment: make this a jQuery object $(this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function the scope (`this`) is the HTML element, not the jQuery object.

Here is a possible fix:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
  .append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td>')
  .mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('list_row_mover');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` returns to the DOM object which has no function `addClass`. Instead, user `$(this)` to point to the jQuery object, which *does* has the function `addClass`.

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
.append('<td class="list_row">'+js2txt(string)+'</td>')
.mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('list_row_mover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(this).addClass("list_row_mover");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$(this)`, which is the jquery object.